# How to get information from Process in java?

Tags: java, process

how to get information form Process in java, use `Runtime.getRuntime.exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler "+url)`, I cannot get anything from the return values's input stream. I want to use java to process browser and get information from the browser's response.

```
Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler " + url); 
//Process pro = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("C:\\Documents\u0008and\u0008Settings\\peiyin.lyy\\Local\u0008Settings\\Application\u0008Data\\Google\\Chrome\\Application\\chrome.exe" + url); 
reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));

String line = null;
Thread.sleep(1000);
while((line=reader.readLine())!=null){
    Thread.sleep(30);
    System.out.println(line);
}
System.out.printl(line);
```

line is null.

Comment: Are you sure that the command you execute is valid ? You could try to test the `process.exitValue()` and/or read the `process.getErrorStream()`

Answer (score 0):

I tried the command **rundll32 url.dll,FileProtocolHandler http://www.google.fr** in a Windows  terminal. There is no output printed on the screen, and the command returns when the browser has been opened.
Since there is nothing to read from the InputStream, it's normal if the line is null.

What kind of information do you want to get from the browser ?